# How to loop an object returned by a function in another function in JS?

Tags: javascript

i've a problem in js. I've a function for example:

```js
function robePersos() {
    var persos = {"player" : "data"};    
    return persos;
}
```

and then i've another function which call robePersos() like this:

```js
function test() {
    var d = robePersos();
    for(var k in d) {
        console.log(k)
    }
}
```

But nothing happens. Why ?

```js
function robePersos() {
  var persos = {
    "player": "data"
  };
  return persos;
}

function test() {
  var d = robePersos();
  for (var k in d) {
    console.log(k)
  }
}
test();
```

**EDIT**
The first snippet works. So, here is my real function:

```js
function robePersos() {
  var persos = {};

  $.get({
         url : 'url',
         success : function(data) {
             var text = $(data).find("div[menu='perso']  a"); //.clone().children().remove().end().text();                            
             $(text).each(function(){
                 perso_name = $(this).text();
                 perso_link = $(this).attr('href');
                                   
                persos[perso_name] = perso_link;
              });
                            
                            
         }
  });
  
  for(var k in persos) {
    console.log(persos[k]);
  }
              
}

robePersos();
```

If I replace the loop by only console.log(persos) it works but the loop return nothing. Why ?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  It seems to be working in the code snippet above.

Comment: It will print the key in your object, 'player'

Comment: console.log(d[k]);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties).

Comment: I've edited the post for explicite the request

Comment: If any of the answers help you, ensure to accept one of them.  thanks.

Comment: Actually no answer help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print both Key and Value, use the following small change in your code.  Your code is printing just the keys.

```js
function robePersos() {
  var persos = {
    "player": "data",
    "anotherPlayer": "anotherData"
  };
  return persos;
}

function test() {
  var d = robePersos();
  for (var k in d) {
    console.log(k, "-" ,d[k]); // change made here.  It prints both.
  }
}
test();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try whith Object.keys()

```
function test() {
  var d = Object.keys(robePersos());
  for (var k in d) {
    console.log(k, "-" ,d[k]); // change made here.  It prints both.
  }
}
```

**Object.keys returns an array whose elements are strings corresponding to the enumerable properties found directly in the object**. The order of the properties is the same as that provided when manually iterating over the properties of the object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys